# Webpack can't resolve asset/resource?

Tags: webpack

I am trying to load an image in a project using webpack

```
asset
  resource
    image.png
src
  components
    global
      module
        module.js
```

In my js file, I have this line

```js
import image from '../../../../asset/resource/image.png'
```

And in my webpack.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  // snip
  module: {
    rules: [
      // snip
      {
        test: /\.png$/i,
        use: 'asset/resource'
      }
    ]
  },
  // snip
}
```

But on start, webpack throw an error:

```sh
ERROR in ./src/components/global/module/module.riot 1:0-86
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'asset/resource' in '/path/to/my/project'
resolve 'asset/resource' in '/path/to/my/project'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /path/to/my/project/package.json (relative path: .)
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in /path/to/my/project/node_modules
        /path/to/my/project/node_modules/asset doesn't exist
      /path/to/my/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /path/to/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /path/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
 @ ./src/components/global/ sync [a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.riot ./module/module.riot
 @ ./src/register-global-components.js 4:32-100
 @ ./src/index.js 4:0-67 7:0-24

webpack 5.66.0 compiled with 1 error in 3616 ms
```

So it looks like webpack doesn't find it's own built in package ? [The doc](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images) s quite clear about t being built in and I don't see the difference with their example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your provided snippet, it looks like it should be `type: 'asset/resource'` instead of `use: 'asset/resource`.

```
module.exports = {
  // snip
  module: {
    rules: [
      // snip
      {
        test: /\.png$/i,
        // use: 'asset/resource'
        type: 'asset/resource'
      }
    ]
  },
  // snip
}
```

Here's the documentation example:

```
 const path = require('path');

 module.exports = {
   entry: './src/index.js',
   output: {
     filename: 'bundle.js',
     path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
   },
   module: {
     rules: [
       {
         test: /\.css$/i,
         use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
       },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource', // EXAMPLE HERE
      },
     ],
   },
 };
```

Comment: Can't test right now, but it looks like I just don't know how to read the documentation. Thanks a lot, will accept your answer as soon as I have the time to go back to that project :)

Comment: Confirmed to be me not reading docs correctly, thanks again !

Comment: No problem, happens to all of us :)

Comment: I had the same problem; HOWEVER! I don't know enough to have typed 'use: ...' So I assert that there is a 'how to' page on the web that I [we?] cut/pasted with the error.   Anyway thanks for documenting this <3